# Scaled down and scaled up versions of Impagliazzo-Wigderson Therem

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, derandomization, pseudorandomness

A famous theorem due to Impagliazzo and Wigderson states that if some function in $E=DTIME[2^{O(n)}]$ requires circuits of size $2^{\Omega(n)}$ then P=BPP.

When can we change $P$ with some complexity class $C$ such that the same result works? In other words, for which complexity classes the following statement is true?

**Statement:** If some function in $E$ requires circuits of size $2^{\Omega(n)}$ then $C= BP-C$.

Here $BP-C$ is the bounded probabilistic version of $C$.

In particular does it work for formulas? I.e. for $C$ equal to logspace uniform $NC_1$ ? In this case the statement would be:

If some function in E requires formulas of size $2^{\Omega(n)}$ then $NC_1 = BP-NC_1$

Comment: I haven't checked the details, but at least you need to scale E down as well: if you want to derandomize NC^1 in place of P,  you need ATIME(O(n)) in place of E (i.e., the exponentially scaled version of NC^1).

Comment: I recommend you check out the paper ["Graph Nonisomorphism Has Subexponential Size Proofs Unless the Polynomial-Time Hierarchy Collapses"](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539700389652) by Klivans and van Melkebeek.